# Pattern recognition algorithm for spots

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

I have such a data, which has a number of XY coordinates (maybe more than a million points)
The coordinates could be random, but it may have some pattern like ring shape.
Can anybody think of a "pattern recognition" method, which can extract certain features from coordinates (not from the images)?

Thank you for your help!
(I had images of an example, but the system doesn't let me post the images. Sorry about that!)

Comment: Can all of the points be part in the pattern, or do you want to detect clusters of different patterns?

Comment: Edit your question to link to your examples, and someone will inline them.

Comment: do you have a small set of shapes to match against?